# How to create MPMediaCollection from NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, swift2, audio-player, mpmediaitem, mpmediaitemcollection

So I make an app that allows users to create their own playlist, and I'm using MediaPlayer framework from iOS. I have no trouble before I update my X Code to latest version, However I got bellow error warning when I updated my X Code :

> ..../playlistV2VC.swift:325:37: Cannot invoke initializer for type 'MPMediaItemCollection' with an argument list of type '(items: MPMediaItem?)'

and here is my code:

```
currentCollectionArray.addObject(User.currentSongAdded!)
var newCollection = MPMediaItemCollection(items: [currentCollectionArray] as? MPMediaItem)
```

User.currentSongAdded! is a new MPMediaItem.

Give me any suggestion doesnt matter obj-c or swift

Comment: This is really easy but you need to explain what `currentCollectionArray` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `currentCollectionArray` is a Swift array of MPMediaItem, then just say `MPMediaItemCollection(items: currentCollectionArray)`.

If it isn't, then it should be. There is no need for you to be working with NSMutableArray here.

If it is an NSMutableArray then you will have to double-cast: `MPMediaItemCollection(items: currentCollectionArray as NSArray as! [MPMediaItem])`.

But seriously, don't use NSMutableArray unless you have to. It isn't worth the pain.

Comment: I've tried using array and append, is the result gonna be the same?

Comment: What "result" are you talking about?

Comment: the MPMediaColelction

Comment: Sure. Look at this code if you don't believe me. https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch16p687AVQueuePlayer/ch29p952AVQueuePlayer/ViewController.swift Look how I form `self.items` into a media item collection and hand it to the queue player. No NSMutableArray here.